# Check in PHP 7.4 whether a property is really initialized or not

Tags: php, properties, php-7.4

I want to check in PHP 7.4 whether a property is really initialized or not. Setting the property to null means it is initialized with null.

I can not use `isset` because it returns false even when it is set to null.
I can not use `property_exists` because it returns true even when it is not initialized.

The only way I know is with `ReflectionProperty::isInitialized`, but that feels a little bit strange, that I need to use this detour.

```
class DTO {
    public ?string $something;
}

$object = new DTO();
$object->something = null;

isset($object->something); //returns false
is_initialized($object->something); //should return true;
```

I could write this function using ReflectionProperty, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I found a request for this on php.net: [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78480). It seems `ReflectionProperty::isInitialized` is the way to go for now.

Answer (score 9):

It is discouraged to do this, see the conversation below [this rejected pull request for implementing an `is_initialized` native PHP function](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/7029).

But if really needed it can be done using the [ReflectionProperty::isInitialized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.isinitialized.php) method.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to catch the access with a `Throwable`. Because if it is strongly typed and is accessed before initialization, it throws an error.